# wp_nav_menu() mark current item ancestor of custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, menus, sub-menu

[This solution](http://www.rarescosma.com/2010/11/add-a-class-to-wp_nav_menu-items-with-urls-included-in-the-current-url/) does almost what I want it to.

Only thing is, I have my menu set up as follows:

```
Menu item 1
Menu item 2
   Custom post type 1
   Custom post type 2
   Custom post type 3
Menu item 3
```

Using the solution I mention adds the tag "current_url" to the sub menu of the custom post type I'm in ("Custom post type 1"). But I want it to add a "current_menu_item" (or something) to "Menu item 2".

Any way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate - does [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97226/building-a-sub-menu-display-parent-category-pages-children-when-viewing-childr/98011#98011) do what you desire? My solution adds a `current-sub` class to all sub-menus that are ancestors of the `current-menu-item` (and/or other menu-item classes).

Answer (score 1):

I do the following, it can be lengthy if you have many post types, feel free to edit it however:

```
/** Edit Nav Menu calsses **/
function custom_wp_nav_classes($classes, $item){
    global $post;
    $page_blog = get_option('page_for_posts');

    if(is_tax('my_taxonomy_name_here') || is_singular('my_post_type_name_here')){

        /** Remove Active Class from Blog **/
        if($item->object_id == $page_blog)
            $classes = array_filter($classes, "remove_parent");

        /** Page ID of what you want to be active **/
        if($item->object_id == 12)
            $classes[] = 'current_page_parent';
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'custom_wp_nav_classes' , 10 , 2);

// Remove Active Class from Blog when viewing CPTs
function remove_parent($var){
    if ($var == 'current_page_parent' || $var == 'current-menu-item' || $var == 'current-page-ancestor') { return false; }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

WordPress handles this by adding the `current_page_ancestor` and/or `current_page_parent` class to the parent item. Try styling those classes similar to `current_menu_item`.

Comment: there are no current tags of any kind to the "main menu item". Which is what I'm trying to find a solution for. I'm assuming it's because I'm using a custom post type.

Comment: are the custom post type links, custom links?

Comment: If you are linking to custom post type archives via a custom link, then WordPress doesn't add any current or ancestor classes. This is a known bug, and there's already a ticket on Trac.

Comment: Thats just not true for custom post types